# Do images need special treatment for high-resolution ("retina") displays vs regular displays?

Tags: resolution, sharpness, web, display, sharpening

What are people's (experimentally tested if possible) views on sharpening images depending on whether they are to be viewed on retina or non-retina devices. 
Assuming resolution in the file is not an issue, which might lead to the higher resolution retina image lacking sharpness simply because there is not enough spatial information available, my thinking would be that the image to be viewed on non-retina devices would need more output sharpening for two reasons:

1. The image is being downsized (more) and therefore loses sharpness due to the interpolation.
2. The image is then essentially being magnified on the non-retina display, which could be considered analagous to either viewing a print up close or printing it on a medium where the ink diffuses a sizeable distance.

Do people agree with this assessment and if so what steps do you take to achieve the extra sharpening for the lower resolution image. E.g. before resizing? After? Or Both?

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, output sharpening is always dependent on the target medium. Optimal quality needs an image which was resized and sharpened for the intended viewing conditions.

A high-res display needs a larger image than a low-res display, and a screen needs differnt sharpening than a print, all of which should, eg., be handled automatically by the Lightroom export dialog if you set size and device correctly. (I.e. i wouldn't set sharpening to high or low for different devices but instead trust LR's logic to apply the correct amount based on the image dimensions.)

If this exercise is worthwhile is a different question, your typical audience probably can't tell the difference anyway, but for optimal quality, you need to serve different images depending on the device.

Comment: But lightroom doesn't know what the display size of the image is. What is the "correct amount"? When standard is chosen? Low? High? What factors would affect whether low, standard, or high output sharpening for screen should be applied, if not the display size or (analogously) how close a print is intended to be viewed. Sharpening specific to the image/taste is applied before output sharpening is applied, so it can't be a matter of "whichever you feel looks best".

Answer (score -7):

Let's get this straight - you're looking to double the amount of sharpening work in your workflow to provide differently (and manually tailored, because otherwise you're wasting your time) content for a small population who...

- are mac users
- possess the type of display you're targeting
- have that display calibrated properly
- were aware that they were receiving a theoretically superior product
- are sitting close enough to their display
- could tell the difference between the two sources if they weren't told which was which
- would actually return enough benefit to you to make that investment worthwhile

Perhaps I'm missing something here but I can't see any cost/benefit analysis making this a worthwhile addition to your workflow.

Comment: "...double the amount of sharpening workflow":
    Double the amount of _italic_ output _italic_ sharpening workflow. Which would be an automated process done in batch, and would constitute only a fraction of my overall sharpening workflow let alone my total workflow.

"manually tailored"
    When is output sharpening manually tailored, other than depending on resizing amount and output medium (which is the point here)?

Comment: "small population who are mac users": 
    I was using the brand name in a generic sense. Almost all phones and tablets on sale today have hi-resolution displays, and desktop products are now following this trend. See [link](http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/a-guide-for-creating-a-better-retina-web/)

Comment: "have that display calibrated properly": I'm afraid I don't understand what calibration you mean.

Comment: "were aware that they were receiving a theoretically superior product": Whether or not they were prepared for the fact that retina technology is not yet globally embraced by the web does not detract from the fact that a retina web is the future and non-retina websites viewed on retina devices look really bad.

Comment: "are sitting close enough to their display": The idea behind retina devices is that their pixels are indiscernible to the human eye at typical viewing distances. You do not need to be sitting extra close to your display to benefit from it.

Comment: "could tell the difference between the two sources if they weren't told which was which": You mean the one with normal output sharpening applied as compared to the one with extra output sharpening? That was my question, and what I was seeking opinion on.

Comment: "would actually return enough benefit to you to make that investment worthwile": I readily admit that my cost/benefit analysis game is seriously sub-par, but since output sharpening needs to be performed anyway, is pretty much an automated process, and since I am exporting each image in multiple sizes anyway, I don't see how it would add that much time, relatively speaking, to the whole process if I applied different amounts of output sharpening to the differently sized images.

Comment: ok... wow - don't think I've ever seen that many comments without the automatic chat invitation  popping up.  Really you need to better understand the sharpening process and why it is only really effective when tuned specifically for each image - explaining that is out of scope of this question and for comments.  But the short answer is that very few people could tell the difference and of those applying a blanket set of sharpening values to your work instead of tailoring them for each image will leave them wondering why you didn't do a better job of your sharpening...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if you appreciate that I'm talking about what is termed output sharpening [here](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-sharpening.htm) as opposed to capture/creative sharpening. I don't understand your viewpoint because before you were saying that it was an excessive amount of work to apply different output sharpening for non-retina/retina images, whereas now you are saying that I need to manually tailor it to each image. Why is more manual tailoring necessary after the "creative sharpening" stage, as it is called in the above article? @James Snell

Comment: My view is that sharpening is always a creative step and to be worthwhile that sharpening needs to be tuned per image/output.  You have a small audience for hi-res devices and potential gains are so minor as to be unnoticeable by most and the few who might notice wouldn't have their enjoyment affected enough to make the investment of your time and effort worthwhile.

Comment: Do you dispute that output sharpening is a necessary step at all then? It doesn't necessarily have to be a laborious process. It could be as simple as using Sharpen For: Screen, Strength: Low for retina images and Sharpen For: Screen, Strength: Medium for non-retina images when exporting in Lightroom If so, then this would add literally nothing (0) to my workflow as it would be as simple as changing the export presets. If this makes the result better then it would clearly be worthwhile. I am merely soliciting opinion. One day very soon we will all be using hi-res devices anyway.

Comment: Please avoid extended conversations in the comments section of a question or answer. That is exactly why we have a chat room. More info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95937/why-must-we-avoid-discussions-in-comments

Comment: I want to echo the chat sentiment, comments are not intended for discussion. I also don't think this answers the question really, which probably explains the volume of down voting...

Comment: @dpollitt Sorry, my bad, I didn't know that. I live to learn!